# Polars - Rendering a dataframe in the densest way possible

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-polars

I am wondering if there is a way to make Polars dataframe renders in jupyter notebooks more dense. As seen in the attached image, Headers and data are both word-wrapped, and there is more than desired padding around cells. Could this be done without tampering with jupyter css files?

[image: Sample screenshot showing word wraps and large padding]

This appears to be controlled by jupyterlab:

[image: screenshot of base.css of jupyterlab]

alter it to:

[image: screenshot of base.css of jupyterlab - altered]

render is now much more suitable for my purposes:

[image: intended render of polars dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

If you want polars to have a different representation on jupyter without changing jupyter at all then that means you have to change polars. The thing to change would be the `_repr_html_` method.

**Stuff for Reference:**

We can look at the existing code for that [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/master/py-polars/polars/dataframe/frame.py)

```
def _repr_html_(self, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    """
    Format output data in HTML for display in Jupyter Notebooks.
    Output rows and columns can be modified by setting the following ENVIRONMENT
    variables:
    * POLARS_FMT_MAX_COLS: set the number of columns
    * POLARS_FMT_MAX_ROWS: set the number of rows
    """
    max_cols = int(os.environ.get("POLARS_FMT_MAX_COLS", default=75))
    if max_cols < 0:
        max_cols = self.shape[1]
    max_rows = int(os.environ.get("POLARS_FMT_MAX_ROWS", default=25))
    if max_rows < 0:
        max_rows = self.shape[0]

    from_series = kwargs.get("from_series", False)
    return "".join(
        NotebookFormatter(
            self,
            max_cols=max_cols,
            max_rows=max_rows,
            from_series=from_series,
        ).render()
    )
```

You can see that this method references the `NotebookFormatter` class which is defined [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/master/py-polars/polars/dataframe/_html.py)

```
class NotebookFormatter(HTMLFormatter):
    """
    Class for formatting output data in HTML for display in Jupyter Notebooks.
    This class is intended for functionality specific to DataFrame._repr_html_().
    """

    def write_style(self) -> None:
        style = """\
            <style>
            .dataframe > thead > tr > th,
            .dataframe > tbody > tr > td {
            text-align: right;
            }
            </style>
        """
        self.write(dedent(style))

    def render(self) -> list[str]:
        """Return the lines needed to render a HTML table."""
        with Tag(self.elements, "div"):
            self.write_style()
            super().render()
        return self.elements
```

You can see that it has a `write_style` method creating a style sheet.  There might be a more elegant way to do this but this seems to work.

**My hack:**

```
from polars.dataframe._html import Tag, HTMLFormatter
from __future__ import annotations

import os
from textwrap import dedent
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Iterable

from polars.dependencies import html

class myNotebookFormatter(HTMLFormatter):
    """
    Class for formatting output data in HTML for display in Jupyter Notebooks.
    This class is intended for functionality specific to DataFrame._repr_html_().
    """

    def write_style(self) -> None:
        style = """\
            <style>
            .dataframe > thead > tr > th,
            .dataframe > tbody > tr {
                padding: 0.1em 0.1em;
                white-space: nowrap;
                }> td {
            text-align: right;
            }
            </style>
        """
        self.write(dedent(style))

    def render(self) -> list[str]:
        """Return the lines needed to render a HTML table."""
        with Tag(self.elements, "div"):
            self.write_style()
            super().render()
        return self.elements
    
def _repr_html_(self, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    """
    Format output data in HTML for display in Jupyter Notebooks.
    Output rows and columns can be modified by setting the following ENVIRONMENT
    variables:
    * POLARS_FMT_MAX_COLS: set the number of columns
    * POLARS_FMT_MAX_ROWS: set the number of rows
    """
    max_cols = int(os.environ.get("POLARS_FMT_MAX_COLS", default=75))
    if max_cols < 0:
        max_cols = self.shape[1]
    max_rows = int(os.environ.get("POLARS_FMT_MAX_ROWS", default=25))
    if max_rows < 0:
        max_rows = self.shape[0]

    from_series = kwargs.get("from_series", False)
    return "".join(
        myNotebookFormatter(
            self,
            max_cols=max_cols,
            max_rows=max_rows,
            from_series=from_series,
        ).render()
    )
        
import polars as pl
pl.DataFrame._repr_html_=_repr_html_
```

All I did was copy paste the internal class and called it `myNotebookFormatter` then in the `write_style` method of that I added the styles that you referenced. (I don't really know css so not sure if that's the right syntax) then I copy pasted the existing `_repr_html_` definition and just changed its call to `NotebookFormatter` and changed it to `myNotebookFormatter`.  Lastly, load `pl` like normal and monkey patch the `_repr_html_` that we defined into `pl.DataFrame._repr_html_`

Comment: Thanks. Monkey patching is not my goto solution, but unless polars devs decide to give 'condensed' representation as an option, I have to go with this..

Comment: as far as the css goes, <style>
            .jp-RenderedHTMLCommon .dataframe td {
                text-align: right;
                padding: 0em;
                white-space: nowrap
            }
            </style> solved it for me. dataframe level css appears to be not specific enough..